# Call of Duty 4 single player crash to desktop

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I just installed Call of Duty 4 and when I try to run the single player mode nothing happens. I just see a quick flicker on the desktop but the game doesn't launch. When I try to run it again, it gives me this message:

> It appears that cod4 did not quit properly the last time it ran. Do you want to run the game in safe mode?

Multiplayer seems to work fine and when I try to switch to single player from the multiplayer menu the same thing happens, it just goes back to my desktop and that message shows up again

Comment: Is this via Steam, or physical disk?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on Windows Vista (yep) and I assume its on Win 7 too. Plug something into the microphone audio jack.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Studoku and Jutschge, your comments don't seem to make any sense. Was this answer edited after you commented, or something? I can't see any edits, looks like a completely ordinary answer to me... do you have some kind of bots commenting? The comments look copy-pasted...?

Comment: @MGOwen the answer was not edited. Since the answering user is fairly new, this answer shows up in the moderation queue. The answer is most likely getting criticized because it lacks explanation for why it would work and/or sources that explain/showcase the solution and reason of the problem.

Comment: No "question" was asked. This provides a solution to the problem that was presented. No one knows why it helps, it just does.

Answer (score 2):

The following 2 actions are known to solve most issues with the game crashing:

- Enable stereo mix
- Plug in an headset/mic

Sources:

http://steamcommunity.com/app/7940/discussions/0/618453594765419915/
http://steamcommunity.com/app/7940/discussions/0/864956555036760746/

Comment: Some people claim that Punkbuster is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

It can be several options. First try to run the game as an administrator and see what happens. Also, if the game is not original you would need a good patch. And finally, uninstall and re-install the game. Sometimes the patches for multiplayer give these kind of problems. Back in the day, with the game beat couldn't play single player anymore.